# AWS Glue from Excel formatted file

Tags: excel, amazon-web-services, csv, xlsx, aws-glue

I have some files in .csv format that I need to crawl from an S3 bucket using AWS glue and then upload to an Aurora RDS using a Glue Job.

They have been saved by a colleague using Excel, but since Excel does not support UTF-8 encoding they are possibly Win-1252 encoded? At any rate, they are not UTF-8 and not being classified correctly by the AWS Glue crawler. Converting files to xlsx or xls does not improve matters, as Glue does not have a classifier for these either.

Aside from saving into text and manually editing each file, what formats can be saved from Excel that AWS Glue would properly crawl and parse? It seems a strange to have no compatability with such a ubiquitous program, even if it is Excel...

Comment: BeardySam did you ever figure out a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as explained at the [AWS Glue Key Concepts doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/components-key-concepts.html), text-based formats must be in UTF-8.

I believe when you export a file in excel using a text format you can choose to use UTF-8 as the encoding, or at least that used to be an option in the past. If you can convert to UTF-8 from Excel, that would be the easiest way to solve your problem.